# Asp.net webform & roled based permission for different folders

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

I have following folder structure in my asp.net webform application.

```
_AdminUser
_ModeratorUser
_EmployeeUser
Images
js
css
ckeditor
App_Code
errorPages
Default.aspx
News.aspx
Article.aspx
```

So far i had only one type of user who used to edit contents of the website.   I used to simply authorise users and redirect authorised user to folder '_AdminUser' so that they

can make changes to the site.

And below code in web.config was enough for me to work without any issue.

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/_Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>

  <location path="_adminUser">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="ckeditor">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

In my new project i have to create three different types of users

1. Admin  User (who is a super user & can have access to all the files in different folder )
2. Moderator User (This type of user can have access to only files in this folder `_ModeratorUser` & other general foleder but no access to `_AdminUser`  or  `_EmployeeUser` )
3. Employee User (This type of user can have access to only files in this folder _EmployeeUser`& other general folder but no access to`_AdminUser`or`_EmployeeUser` )

In order to achieve this i have create three types of roles `Admin` , `Moderator` and `Employee`. When i create new user I assign it to specific role and i want each role to have access to different folder as described above.

but i am not sure how i can modify web.config file so that i can achieve this kind of role based permission. I have been looking for such tutorial but no luck so far. other tutorial which i looked at doesn't seem to address my problem. I would appreciate a pointer in right direction.

Comment: I found this tutorial which seems to address my issue `http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ishbandhu2009/role-based-authorization/` i will try and see if it works

Answer (score 3):

I assume you use ASP.Net Membership and Role provider. If so, you need a separate web.config in each folder to restrict permission.

### web.config inside Admin folder

The following web.conf setting (located inside Admin folder) allows only users in `Admin` role accessing files inside Admin folder. Other users cannot access those files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Admin" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I tried this approach for some reason it did not work so i tool a different which i will post as a solution. Logically your solution should work but i tried same approach before but it didnt work for me.

Comment: The above idea is to keep the specific folder's setting inside the folder instead of main web.config. However, your solution also useful if you want to centralize config setting in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

You [have](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) here a very good tutorial and you even can download a tool for administrate user, roles, permissions. You can download the source code from the bottom of the page, on the attachments section.

Answer (score 0):

Web.Config Setting

```
  <!--Path: folder path -->
  <location path="_adminUser">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <!-- Allow user who have Admin role can access the AdminUser folder aspx pages -->
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <!-- Other user can not access AdminUser folder aspx pages -->
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <!--Path: folder path -->
  <location path="_EmployeeUser">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <!-- Allow user who have Client role can access the ClientUser folder aspx pages -->
        <allow roles="Employee"/>
        <!-- Other user can not access ClientUser folder aspx pages -->
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

I also wrote following code for my Login Control Button

protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // please don't use User.IsInRole here , because it will not be populated yet at this stage.

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Admin"))
{
    Login1.DestinationPageUrl = "~/_adminUser/Default.aspx";
}
else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Heroes"))
{
    Login1.DestinationPageUrl = "~/_EmployeeUser/Default.aspx";
    }
}
```

Above approach is working for me but it has a drawback that i have to code in every time a new role is added. I am not sure which separate web.config file for related for is not working as mentioned in one of the solution.